Problem 5.17 in Fulton's Algebra Curves.
I am writing a problem from Fulton's book. This is the problem.
Let $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4\in\mathbb{P}^2$. Let $V$ be the linear system of conics passing through these points. Show that $\dim{V}=2$ if $P_1,\cdots,P_4$ lie on a line, and $\dim{V}=1$ otherwise.
This is my proof: First note that $V=V(2;P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4)$, and $$\mathbb{P}^5\cong V(2)\supseteq V(2;P_1)\supseteq V(2;P_1,P_2)\supseteq V(2;P_1,P_2,P_3)\supseteq V(2;P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4).$$ Then $\dim V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4)\geq 1$ and $\dim V(2;P_1,P_2,P_3)=2$, hence $$1\leq\dim V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4)\leq V(2;P_1,P_2,P_3)=2.$$
If $P_1,\cdots,P_4$ lie on a line, say this line is $L(X,Y,Z)$, which is a form of degree $1$. Hence in this case, each conics $F$ have the form $F(X,Y,Z)=L(X,Y,Z)G(X,Y,Z)$, since $\deg F=2$, $\deg G=1$. Hence, $$\dim V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4)=3-1=2.$$
If $\dim V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4)=2$, let $P_5$ be a point distinct from $P_1,\cdots,P_4$, consider $V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4,P_5)$. By Bezout theorem, two conics have $5$ points in common, then they have a common componet, this component must be a line. Hence, each conic in $V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4,P_5)$ have the form $F(X,Y,Z)=L(X,Y,Z)G(X,Y,Z)$. This implies, there are at least $4$ points lie on common componet.
Hence, $\dim V(2;P_1,\cdots,P_4)=2$ iff $4$ points lie on a line, and therefore, if $P_1,\cdots,P_4$ not lie on a line, we have $\dim V =1$.
I am not sure if my proof is correct. Could you help me check the proof?
Here are some symbols and definitions that will be used：

Let $F$ be any curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Write $F=F_m+F_{m+1}+\cdots+F_n$, where $F_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $k[X,Y]$ of degree $i$, $F_m\neq 0$. We define $m$ to be the multiplicity of $F$ at $P$, write $m=m_P(F)$.

Let $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ be distinct points in $\mathbb{P}^2$, $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ nonnegative integers. We set $$V(d;r_1P_1,\cdots,r_nP_n)=\{\text{curves }F\text{ of degree }d:m_{P_i}(F)\geq r_i, 1\leq i\leq n\}.$$



How do you make a conclusion, that "there are at least 4
points lie on common component"?

Also, when you write $V(2)\supseteq V(2;P_1)\supseteq V(2;P_1,P_2)$ and so on, it may be a good idea to explain, that at each step we add one linear equation, hence the dimension either stays the same or decreases by 1.
